# Server-Side Blazor - Post Form Data To Controller Gets 400 Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

Using Server-side Blazor, I'd like to post data to my controller from a form but keep getting 400 errors. I have attempted a wide array of different fix implimentations but I seem to be missing something that could be obvious. All relevant code is below.

MacroModel.cs

```
    public class MacroModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Age { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Weight { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int HeightFt { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int HeightIn { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ActivityLevel { get; set; }
    }
```

PersonController.cs

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PersonController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        private IMacroCalcService _MacroService = new MacroCalcService();
        //[ResponseType(typeof(MacroModel))]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> FromMacroCalculator([FromBody]MacroModel macros)
        {
            var m = macros; //ignore this
            var totalMacros = await _MacroService.startCalculation();
            return Ok(totalMacros);
        }
    }
```

MacroCalculator.razor

```
@page "/macrocalculator"
@using Services
@using FoodAndFitnessTracker.Models
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@using System.Net.Http.Headers
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject IMacroCalcService MacroService
<h1>Macro Calculator</h1>

<EditForm Model="@macroModel" OnValidSubmit="@calculateMacros">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="gender">Gender: </label>
            <InputSelect id="gender" @bind-Value="macroModel.Gender">
                <option value="">Select Gender</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </InputSelect>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="age">Age </label>
        <InputNumber Id="age" Name="age" Class="form-control" @bind-Value="macroModel.Age" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="weight">Weight (in lbs): </label>
        <InputNumber Id="weight" name="weight" Class="form-control" @bind-Value="macroModel.Weight" />
    </div>

    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            Height <br />
            <label for="height-ft">ft</label>
            <InputNumber Id="height-ft" Class="form-control" max="1" @bind-Value="macroModel.HeightFt" />

            <label for="height-in">in </label>
            <InputNumber Id="height-in" Class="form-control" max="2" @bind-Value="macroModel.HeightIn" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="activity-level">Activity Level: </label>
            <InputSelect id="activity-level" @bind-Value="macroModel.ActivityLevel">
                <option value="">Select Level</option>
                <option value="Sedentary">Sedentary</option>
                <option value="Moderately-Active">Moderately Active</option>
                <option value="Active">Active</option>
            </InputSelect>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <button type="submit">Ok</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private MacroModel macroModel { get; set; } = new MacroModel();
    private async Task calculateMacros()
    {
        //List<MacroModel> mac = new List<MacroModel>();
        //var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mac, Formatting.Indented);
        //var stringContent = new StringContent(json);
        Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(macroModel, Formatting.None);
        var stringContent = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var resr = Http.PostAsync("api/Person/FromMacroCalculator", stringContent).Result;
        await MacroService.startCalculation();
        //NavHelper.NavigateTo("/showmacros");
    }
}
```

ConfigureServices

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IMacroCalcService, MacroCalcService>();
            //services.AddHttpClient();
            //Server Side Blazor doesn't register HttpClient by default
            if (!services.Any(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(HttpClient)))
            {
                // Setup HttpClient for server side in a client side compatible fashion
                services.AddScoped<HttpClient>(s =>
                {
                    // Creating the URI helper needs to wait until the JS Runtime is initialized, so defer it.
                    var uriHelper = s.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
                    return new HttpClient
                    {
                        BaseAddress = new Uri(uriHelper.BaseUri)
                    };
                });
            }
        }
```

I have tried using PostAsJsonAsync, same thing sadly.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, upload your complete app to github so that we can run and inspect it. The code you provided in your question is not complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inject in the .razor file:

```
@inject HttpClient http;

@inject NavigationManager navigationManager;
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

and do the POST call in .razor:

```
 var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourmodal);
 var stringContent = new StringContent(serialized, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

 var result = await http.PostAsync($"{navigationManager.BaseUri}api/method", stringContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Setup.cs:

```
  services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();
```

Controller :

```
 [HttpPost] 
 public IActionResult Login([FromBody]Model login)
 {
      IActionResult response = Ok(new { result = ''});
 }
```

Comment: Make your modal class as    [Serializable] and try.

Comment: It seems that you created an api for managing user login from an blazor page. I am trying something similiar but don't get it running, since my blazor app still says unauthorized, even after successfull login inside the api. Could you please share some more of your code?